# FileNotFoundException when loading my-project.core with an external dependency

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

I receive `FileNotFoundException` in Clojure REPL, when trying to use an external library. For example, I create a new project with `lein new example-twitter-project`. Then I edit files:

`project.clj`:

```
(defproject example-twitter-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [clojure-twitter "1.2.6-SNAPSHOT"]])
```

`src/example-twitter-project/core.clj`:

```
(ns example-twitter-project.core
  (:use 'twitter))
```

Then I run `lein deps`, and then `lein repl`.

```
example-twitter-project$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 23833
user=> (use :reload-all 'example-twitter-project.core)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate quote/twitter__init.class or quote/twitter.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
```

In the same time, I can `use` the external library from the REPL directly:

```
user=> (use 'twitter)
nil
user=> (doc twitter/with-oauth)
-------------------------
twitter/with-oauth
([consumer access-token access-token-secret & body])
Macro
  Set the OAuth access token to be used for all contained Twitter requests.
nil
```

What should I do to be able to use this external library in the project?

If I add `-main` function and try to run the script, I get similar `FileNotFoundException`, so this is not only a REPL issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate quote/twitter__init.class or quote/twitter.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate quote/twitter__init.class or quote/twitter.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
...
```

Please note that the name of the library and its namespace are different. Could it be the cause?

P.S. `lein version`: Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_24 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `quote` in the `(ns (:use ...))`, so your code will look like:

```
(ns example-twitter-project.core
  (:use twitter))
```

Answer (score 5):

in `ns` declarations you need to not quote ns names, and in `use` expressions you have to quote them

```
(ns example-twitter-project.core
  (:use twitter))
```

This is because the ns macro sees it's arguments before they are evaluated to it sees the symbol `twitter` instead of looking up the value of twitter. when calling `use` from the REPL the symbol twitter would be evaluated before `use` gets to see it, unless you use quote to prevent this.